# MapStruct: initialize using updateMethod(), create even though source is null

Tags: java, mapstruct

could someone tell me how (or if it is even possible) to force update method to create target if it is null?

I would like to achieve something like this:

```java
    @BeforeMapping
    @Mapping(source = "inputBy", target = "tactical.inputBy")
    default BCSecuritiesTrade updateOrCreateInputBy(String inputBy, @MappingTarget BCSecuritiesTrade bcSecuritiesTrade){
        return bcSecuritiesTrade != null? bcSecuritiesTrade:new BCSecuritiesTrade();
    }
```

but this returns always new instance and does not do the mapping.

I would like to have method, which update the "target" when it is present and create new "target" object when null was entered.

Also when "source" object is null it should not return null, but the "target" object or create new one if "target" object is null. Currently method is returning null when "source" is null.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not found out of box solution.
It seems MapStruct is designed to use `updateMethod` only for existing instances, according to [documentation](https://mapstruct.org/documentation/dev/reference/html/#updating-bean-instances).

I resolved problem via additional custom method.

**MapStruct version 1.4.2.Final**

```java
@Mapper
public interface BCSecuritiesTradeMapper {
    BCSecuritiesTradeMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(BCSecuritiesTradeMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source = "inputBy", target = "tactical.inputBy")
    BCSecuritiesTrade updateInputBy(String inputBy, @MappingTarget BCSecuritiesTrade bcSecuritiesTrade);

    default BCSecuritiesTrade updateOrCreateInputBy(String inputBy, BCSecuritiesTrade bcSecuritiesTrade) {
        if (bcSecuritiesTrade == null) {
            bcSecuritiesTrade = new BCSecuritiesTrade();
        }
        if (inputBy == null) {
            return bcSecuritiesTrade;
        }
        return updateInputBy(inputBy, bcSecuritiesTrade);
    }
}
```

Generated code:

```java
public class BCSecuritiesTradeMapperImpl implements BCSecuritiesTradeMapper {
    @Override
    public BCSecuritiesTrade updateInputBy(String inputBy, BCSecuritiesTrade bcSecuritiesTrade) {
        if ( inputBy == null ) {
            return null;
        }
        if ( bcSecuritiesTrade.tactical == null ) {
            bcSecuritiesTrade.tactical = new Tactical();
        }
        stringToTactical( inputBy, bcSecuritiesTrade.tactical );

        return bcSecuritiesTrade;
    }

    protected void stringToTactical(String string, Tactical mappingTarget) {
        if ( string == null ) {
            return;
        }
        mappingTarget.inputBy = string;
    }
}
```

**MapStruct version 1.5.0.RC1**

The new version has better implementation. In case if the `source` is `null` `target` will be returned, but it still can not create an instance of the `target` object in case passed `null`.

Custom method is simplified but did not eliminate.

```java
@Mapper
public interface BCSecuritiesTradeMapper {
    BCSecuritiesTradeMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(BCSecuritiesTradeMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source = "inputBy", target = "tactical.inputBy")
    BCSecuritiesTrade updateInputBy(String inputBy, @MappingTarget BCSecuritiesTrade bcSecuritiesTrade);

    default BCSecuritiesTrade updateOrCreateInputBy(String inputBy, BCSecuritiesTrade bcSecuritiesTrade) {
        if (bcSecuritiesTrade == null) {
            bcSecuritiesTrade = new BCSecuritiesTrade();
        }
        return updateInputBy(inputBy, bcSecuritiesTrade);
    }
}
```

Generated code:

```java
public class BCSecuritiesTradeMapperImpl implements BCSecuritiesTradeMapper {

    @Override
    public BCSecuritiesTrade updateInputBy(String inputBy, BCSecuritiesTrade bcSecuritiesTrade) {
        if ( inputBy == null ) {
            return bcSecuritiesTrade;
        }
        if ( bcSecuritiesTrade.tactical == null ) {
            bcSecuritiesTrade.tactical = new Tactical();
        }
        stringToTactical( inputBy, bcSecuritiesTrade.tactical );
        return bcSecuritiesTrade;
    }

    protected void stringToTactical(String string, Tactical mappingTarget) {
        if ( string == null ) {
            return;
        }
        mappingTarget.inputBy = string;
    }
}
```

**Unit test:**

```java
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.JUnit4;

@RunWith(JUnit4.class)
public class MapperTest {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        BCSecuritiesTrade bcSecuritiesTrade = BCSecuritiesTradeMapper.INSTANCE.updateOrCreateInputBy(null, null);
        Assert.assertNotNull(bcSecuritiesTrade);
        Assert.assertNull(bcSecuritiesTrade.tactical);

        BCSecuritiesTrade bcSecuritiesTradeUpdate = BCSecuritiesTradeMapper.INSTANCE.updateOrCreateInputBy(null, bcSecuritiesTrade);
        Assert.assertNotNull(bcSecuritiesTradeUpdate);
        Assert.assertNull(bcSecuritiesTradeUpdate.tactical);
        Assert.assertEquals(bcSecuritiesTrade, bcSecuritiesTradeUpdate);

        bcSecuritiesTrade = BCSecuritiesTradeMapper.INSTANCE.updateOrCreateInputBy("123", null);
        Assert.assertNotNull(bcSecuritiesTrade);
        Assert.assertEquals(bcSecuritiesTrade.tactical.inputBy, "123");

        bcSecuritiesTradeUpdate = BCSecuritiesTradeMapper.INSTANCE.updateOrCreateInputBy("124", bcSecuritiesTrade);
        Assert.assertNotNull(bcSecuritiesTradeUpdate);
        Assert.assertEquals(bcSecuritiesTradeUpdate.tactical.inputBy, "124");
        Assert.assertEquals(bcSecuritiesTrade, bcSecuritiesTradeUpdate);

    }
}
```

**Entities that were used:**

```java
public class BCSecuritiesTrade {
    public Tactical tactical;
}

public class Tactical {
    public String inputBy;
}
```

**Alternative solution:**

Creare two separete methods for `Create` and `Update`.

```java
@Mapper(nullValueMappingStrategy = NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_DEFAULT)
public interface BCSecuritiesTradeMapper {
    BCSecuritiesTradeMapper INSTANCE = Mappers.getMapper(BCSecuritiesTradeMapper.class);

    @Mapping(source = "inputBy", target = "tactical.inputBy")
    BCSecuritiesTrade updateInputBy(String inputBy, @MappingTarget BCSecuritiesTrade bcSecuritiesTrade);

    @Mapping(source = "inputBy", target = "tactical.inputBy")
    BCSecuritiesTrade createInputBy(String inputBy);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Eugene, your answer is awesome. It explains a lot of problems I had. Thank you!!!